# findcontrol in .cs class from webcontrol

Tags: c#, .net, ascx, webusercontrol

I have some webusercontrols ".ascx" and want place some code into function class in App_Code folder, however when I try this code I keep getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

```
 public static void Layout()
    {
    Page pg = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;
    PlaceHolder PH = (PlaceHolder)pg.FindControl("PHolder");
}
```

Comment: Can you explain more info about in which line do you get the null? In 'pg' or 'PH'?

Comment: I think his placeholder PH is null because the lifecycle of the page is not done yet. I suppose that he may be able to find his control if he use the form["Id_form"]... (only supposition here)

Comment: getting this error: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: As per the above code the exception should happen in second line. The pg object is null and when it tries to call FindControl, the exception is thrown. From where and under what context are you calling this method?

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting null and not an exception, then that means that `Page` is evaluating properly. However, something that may not be is

```
PlaceHolder PH = (PlaceHolder)pg.FindControl("PHolder");
```

It's unlikely that the PHolder control actually belongs to the page. Most likely this control belongs to some child control. The `FindControl()` method is not a recursive function. It will only look in the control collection that immediately belongs to it. In order for this to work you will either need to pass in the actual parent control where you expect to find this PHolder or overload/extend the FindControl method in System.Web.UI.Page (or your baseclass if you're using one) to be recursive. Be careful with this method though because pages can have a LOT of controls and this kind of recursion can be come decisively heavy.

If the PHolder control is common across all of your pages, it might not be a bad idea to place a property in a baseclass that holds a reference to this PHolder object and access it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this helps but I have an ascx that calls a function in aspx page and that function does whatever it is I need..

```
//ascx

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
((aspxpage)this.Page).functionName();
}

//aspx

public void functionName()
{
//Call function in app_code class
}
```